# Populate database for quarkus native tests using liquibase

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, liquibase, quarkus, testcontainers

I'd like to populate database with some data using liquibase for native tests in quarkus. Currently I have three profiles: `prod` `dev` `test`. JVM tests are successful but for when building native application the native tests fails (eg. with `-Dquarkus.profile=dev -Dquarkus.test.native-image-profile=test`):

```
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_locks" does not exist
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "qrtz_triggers" does not exist
```

Also I'd like to point out, that I want to run native tests with profile `test` for each profile I have (`prod`, `dev`, `test`). The command I'm using to run native tests:

```
./gradlew clean build testNative -Dquarkus.package.type=native -Dquarkus.native.container-build=true -Dquarkus.native.builder-image=quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:20.3.0-java11 -Dquarkus.profile=<profile> -Dquarkus.test.native-image-profile=test
```

`build.gradle`:

```
...
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-quartz'
implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
...
testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-liquibase'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:testcontainers'
testImplementation 'org.testcontainers:postgresql'
...
```

`application.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
```

`application-dev.properties`:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
quarkus.datasource.username=db
quarkus.datasource.password=db
```

`application-test.properties`:

```
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.liquibase.change-log=<path-to-changelog>
```

For JVM tests, liquibase is populating database in testcontainers with quartz tables, but for native tests it doesn't.

Without `testNative` the application builds to native and runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Could you post logs for liquibase runs?  For the native test runs?  I don't know quartz or quarkus well but looking at the run logs for liquibase between test caontainers for quartz tables vs. native tests may help.  I'd be curious if the URL and credentials for native tests environments are correct.